# row editable data table column with dialog in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF. I am using row editable data table in JSF primefaces. In row editable datatable input text column it have two ajax calls.one is blur and another one is Commandbuuton. I want to get value from this input text column from backing bean.

Here is my Code:

```
<h:form id="frm1">
<p:dataTable var="fert" value="#{fertilizerEntryBean.fertList}" id="fertList" editable="true"  scrollable="true" scrollWidth="900" scrollHeight="250" >

                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{fertilizerEntryBean.onEdit}" update=":frm1:messages :frm1:ha_amount" />  
                            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{fertilizerEntryBean.onCancel}" update=":frm1:messages :frm1:ha_amount" />  
                            <p:column headerText="...." width="15">
                                <p:rowEditor />  
                            </p:column>
<p:column headerText="Receiver Plot No." width="150">
                                <p:cellEditor>  
                                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{fert.receiverPlot}" /></f:facet>  
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText id="receiverPlot" value="#{fert.receiverPlot}" size="15">
                                            <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{fertilizerEntryBean.loadReceiverDetails(fert)}" update="receiverCode,receiverName"/>
                                        </p:inputText>&nbsp;
                                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" style="height: 25px;position: absolute;" onclick="receiver_dialog.show();"/>
                                    </f:facet>  
                                </p:cellEditor>  
                            </p:column>
</p:datatable>
</h:form>
<h:form id="receiverForm">
            <p:dialog widgetVar="receiver_dialog" id="receiver_dialog">
                <p:dataTable id="receiver_table" value="#{fertilizerEntryBean.mediumFertModel}" selection="#{fertilizerEntryBean.selectedList}" selectionMode="single" var="fert" rows="10" liveScroll="true"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{fertilizerEntryBean.onRowSelect}" update=':frm1:fertList:receiverPlot'/>
                    <p:column id="state_id_column" headerText="Receiver Code">
                        <h:outputText value="#{fert.receiverPlot}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:commandButton style="alignment-adjust: central;" value='OK' onclick="receiver_dialog.hide();"/>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

And my Bean Class:

```
public class FertilizerEntryBean implements Serializable{
private List<FertModel> fertList=null;
private FertDataModel mediumFertModel;
private FertModel selectedList;
public List<FertModel> getFertList() {
    return fertList;
}

public void setFertList(List<FertModel> fertList) {
    this.fertList = fertList;
}
public FertDataModel getMediumFertModel() {
    getReceiverCode();
    return mediumFertModel;
}

public void setMediumFertModel(FertDataModel mediumFertModel) {
    this.mediumFertModel = mediumFertModel;
}

public FertModel getSelectedList() {
    return selectedList;
}

public void setSelectedList(FertModel selectedList) {
    this.selectedList = selectedList;
}
public List<FertModel> getReceiverCode(){
Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
try{
    List<DosVendormaster> vendorList=session.createCriteria(DosVendormaster.class).add(Restrictions.eq("vendortype", "CGRV")).add(Restrictions.eq("block", "X")).list();
    if(vendorList.size()>0){
        for (Iterator<DosVendormaster> it = vendorList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            DosVendormaster dosVendormaster = it.next();
            fertList.add(new FertModel(dosVendormaster.getSapVendorcode()));
        }
        mediumFertModel=new FertDataModel(fertList);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    session.close();
}
return fertList;
}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(" Selected", ((FertModel)        event.getObject()).getReceiverPlot());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    FertModel fert=new FertModel();
    fert.setReceiverPlot(((FertModel) event.getObject()).getReceiverPlot());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(id)` where id is something like `frm1:fert:(rowIndex):receiverPlot`. That's how you can find component and use getValue for that component. You can take rowIndex by setting `rowIndexVar` attributte to your datatable

Comment: Now I am able to find the Component through your Knowledge but I am unable to set selected value from data table for this component.

Comment: Can you be more precise about you are unable to set selected value from data table for this component.

Comment: If you have a problem with `rowSelect` check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853329/multiple-selection-strange-behaviour

Comment: I got the selected value from data table. My problem is to set that selected value into this component.